# How to use variables in sed line deletion

Tags: sed

I have a variable with the value of 6

```
$ echo $line_number
6
```

When I use sed to remove all lines except 0 - 6, it works as expected

```
$ sed "0,6!d" ~/myfile
```

When I try to substitute the number 6 with my variable, I get an error

```
$ sed "0,$line_number!d" ~/myfile
bash: !d": event not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the `!` character which in `bash`, when interactive, even inside double quotes triggers [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html).

That feature comes from csh (where it's actually worse) and is also found in bash and zsh but otherwise not a standard `sh` feature.

In `bash` and `zsh`, contrary to `csh`, history expansion doesn't occur inside single quotes, so `sed '0,6!d'` would be OK. But `sed "0,6!d"` is not OK. In interactive `bash` shells, `!d` expands to the last command that contained `d`.

You can remove `!`'s special meaning with:

```
sed "0,$line_number"'!d'
```

I personally disable the history expansion feature as modern shells have much better interactive equivalents. I disable it in `zsh` with `set +o banghist`, you can disable it in `bash` with `set +o histexpand` (actually, `zsh` added `histexpand` as an alias to `banghist` in 3.1.2 in 1997 for compatibility with `bash`, so `set +o histexpand` will work in `zsh` as well). In `(t)csh`, you can disable history expansion with `set histchars`. The `histchars=` equivalent actually also works in `bash` and `zsh`.

Note that the `0` address is a GNU `sed` extension. Portably, you can use `head` instead (which is also going to be more efficient):

```
head -n "$line_number"
```

With `sed`, portably, you'd use:

```
sed "${line_number}q"
```

Which is also more efficient as `sed` stops reading after the `$line_number`<sup>th</sup> line instead of carrying on reading but discarding all the other lines.